# COUNTIF in ARRAYFORMULA (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count a specific word that is located, for example, in E2 in a range of B2:E2. I use **COUNTIF** and everything works perfect:

```
COUNTIF(B2:E2, E2)
```

After that i want to automate the process and put it into **ARRAYFORMULA**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
       COUNTIF((B2:B):(E2:E), E2:E)
 )
```

Suddenly, it counts E2 word not on each row, but also on every row beneath.
On the linked screenshot i showed how it supposes to work. E2 is a "Hunter" word and there are only 4 hunters on this row that must be counted *(the given code counts every hunter beneath that range B-E aswell)*.

[ExampleScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGw7v.png)

I've red that **COUNTIF** doesn't really work that well with **ARRAYFORMULA**. Is there any work around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E4="";;MMULT((B2:E4=E2:E4)*1; {1;1;1;1})))
```

[image]